# Merge into questions

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I am trying to copy all values of two different records for same table so I use Merge Into like this:

```
Merge into mytable target
    using (select * from mytable where pk = :p1_original) source
    on (target.pk = :p2_new)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET ...
```

And it work so I tried to use `Merge Into` like this:

```
Merge into mytable target
    using mytable source
    on (target.pk = :p2_new) and (source.pk = :p1_original)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET ...
```

And it also work but I want to ask are both scripts work the same way specially in performance ?

Another question I saw in the documentation they use `Update` after `WHEN MATCHED THEN` can I use more SQL statements or I am allowed to use `Update` only ?

Where pk is mytable primary key (Integer)
p1_original is the primary key value for the record I want to copy from
p2_new is the primary key value for the record I want to copy to

Comment: You are asking two different questions, consider posting them as separate questions